# Rails form submit via ajax post not calling success or error callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, post

I have a rails 4  application where I have a contact form which I post to my rails endpoint to process it, send out an email, and then send back json with a redirect url to the client.

my html form is like so:

```
<form name="contact_form" action="/contact" class="forms" >
            <fieldset>
              <ol>
                <li class="form-row text-input-row name-field">
                  <input type="text" name="name" class="text-input defaultText required" title="Name (Required)"/>
                </li>
                <li class="form-row text-input-row email-field">
                  <input type="text" name="email" class="text-input defaultText required email" title="Email (Required)"/>
                </li>
                <li class="form-row text-input-row subject-field">
                  <input type="text" name="subject" class="text-input defaultText" title="Subject"/>
                </li>
                <li class="form-row text-area-row">
                  <textarea name="message" class="text-area required"></textarea>
                </li>
                <li class="form-row hidden-row">
                  <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="" />
                </li>
                <li class="button-row">
                  <input onclick="contact_email()" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-submit bm0" />
                </li>
              </ol>
              <input type="hidden" name="v_error" id="v-error" value="Required" />
              <input type="hidden" name="v_email" id="v-email" value="Enter a valid email" />
            </fieldset>
          </form>
```

My javascript function is:

```
function contact_email(){
    form = $('form')
    form_data = document.forms.contact_form;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form_data,
        dataType: "JSON",
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            window.location = data.redirect_url;
        },
        error: function(xhr, status) {
            alert(status);
        }
    });
}
```

(I have tried with an without async: false many times, as well as return false; at the end of function without it working)

and my rails endpoint to process the POST

```
def contact_email
    UserMailer.contact_email(params).deliver
    flash[:message] = "Thank you for contacting us! We'll be in touch shortly"
    res = {:redirect_url => root_url}    
    render :json => JSON.generate(res)
end
```

After my javascript fires, the contact_email endpoint is hit, and it sends out the JSON response perfectly fine.

The response is

```
{"redirect_url":"http://localhost:3000/"}
```

Yet neither my ajax success or error callback is ever executed.

Why is this?

EDIT:

This may not be relevant, but I do see one console error in browser dev tools

Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

for jquery-1.11.1.js

Comment: Using Firebug in Firefox, or Developer Tools in Chrome, what is shown as the response in the Net tab for the ajax call? And are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: I stated above, http 200 application/json with response body as {"redirect_url":"http://localhost:3000/"}

Comment: If instead of `data: form_data,` you put `data: form.serialize(),` does the Illegal Invocation error go away, and does anything else happen?

Comment: Does your page reload after clicking submit ? is your `contact_email()` function fired ?

Comment: I can see you said you tried returning false but since you are using `type="submit"`, then you need to do a `return false` at the end of the function to prevent it from submitting.

Comment: Yes the contact_email method is fired or else I wouldn't have been hitting my server and getting JSON back.

Comment: Ah changing data to form.serialize() worked perfect. Why is that? Did return false also have some impact? Please post an answer @mccannf and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are getting `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` in the console, usually this means you are trying to pass a HTML element via the `data` attribute, which JQuery does *not* like. If you use [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) it converts the form into a string containing a series of url-encoded name-value pairs which is then readily passed via ajax.

It seems in this case that the ajax call actually completed the POST request and then subsequently fails on the Illegal invocation, which means the subsequent success or error callbacks do not get executed.

So - just serialize your form like so:

```
function contact_email(){
    form = $('form')

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: "JSON",
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            window.location = data.redirect_url;
        },
        error: function(xhr, status) {
            alert(status);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set form as remote:true.

this says that submit the form using ajax rather than following forms action.

Comment: As you can see above, I'm not using rails form() method to generate html. However, when I added data-remote="true" to the form html, it had no effect.